# How do you find the first element of a path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just downloaded Python 3.4 and I'm wondering how you would go about finding the first directory of a relative path?  I.e. given the path `a/b/c/d` I would like to print `a`.

The closest I've gotten is:

```
from pathlib import Path
print(list(Path('a/b/c/d').parents)[-2])
```

or

```
p = Path('a/b/c/d')
print(p.parents[len(p.parents) - 2])
```

in both cases the `-2` part is a bit magical.  I've read the docs and the PEP, and haven't found any better way.. did I miss something obvious?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`parts`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts) attribute:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path('a/b/c/d').parts
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> Path('a/b/c/d').parts[0]
'a'
```

Answer (score 3):

[Path.parts](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html?highlight=path#pathlib.PurePath.parts) is what you need.

```
p = Path("a/b/c/d")
print(p.parts[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#methods-and-properties), `parents` gives you *an immutable sequence providing access to the logical ancestors of the path*; the last element of that sequence would be the logical root, and the *second to last* element would then be the first directory in the path, which is what you're looking for. That is why you need to use the `p.parents[len(p.parents)-2]` shortcut ('-2' is for the 'second to last' element of a list).

Note that `parents` always gives you full formed paths. If you only want the directory name you might want to use `p.parts` instead. In that case the first element is the logical root, so you'd want `p.parts[1]`.

Comment: Fixed. The meaning of the '-2' is still the same, though, accessing the 'second to last' path because the last one is just the logical root.